# Working to get scrolling on mobile devices, works on desktops. Using fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll, fullpage.js

I'm working on a some-what basic site, but have an issue we can't seem to get passed. (site not complete)

It's a horizontal size, laid out using fullPage.js.
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

When you click the Sign up button in the top right corner, the slide container scrolls all the way left, displaying an iframe, loaded with a CRM.

We're using a callback in the fullPage plugin to know when a user has scrolled to that page. When the page with the iframe is loaded, a script runs to resize the height of the iframe to the available screen-estate ( win height - header & footer ).

Problem is, scrolling doesn't work on Iphone. Works fine on desktop.
Can't seem to figure out what's going on. Have read up on scrolling in iframes on iOS devices, but haven't stumbled upon a viable solution.

url: go-combine.com

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using the fullPage.js option `normalScrollElements` for the iframe?

Comment: Have tried it with & without. When I did use it, it was set as: `normalScrollElements : 'iframe'`.

I just added it back to re-confirm.

Comment: Try updating the value of `normalScrollElementTouchThreshold`, which is set by default to 5. Use a higher one. 10, 20...

Comment: Added  `normalScrollElementTouchThreshold : 20`. No changes in symptom. FYI: Testing on Safari, iOS 8.1.2.